# I am using select 2 multiselect drop down in laravel .On click select all all values get selected in laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am using select2 (multi-select) drop down in laravel.

Here I am using the world wide web option it clicks all options get select selected. But the worldwide web also gets selected I want only option values et selected not World Wide web(Select All) option come in the select box. How to fix it?

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="service_continent">Service Continent</label>
        <div class="select2-purple">

            <select id="service_continent" class="form-control form-select form-select-lg col-lg-12 service_continent" multiple="multiple" aria-label=".form-select-lg example" data-dropdown-css-class="select2-purple" name="service_continent[]" style="height:50px !important;">
            <!-- <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" >Select All -->
            <option value=''>Select Continent</option>
            <option value="World Wide">World Wide</option>
                @foreach($continents as $index => $continent)
                <!-- <option value="{{ $index }}" @if(isset($company) && $company->service_continent == $index || old('service_continent')===$index) selected @endif>{{ $continent }}</option> -->
                <option value="{{ $index }}" @if(isset($company) && in_array($index,$serviceContinent)|| (old('service_continent') && in_array($index, old('service_continent')))) selected @endif>{{ $continent }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            
            @if ($errors->has('service_continent'))
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('service_continent') }}</span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
    
  
var service_continent = $('.service_continent').select2();
    $('.service_continent').on("select2:select", function (e) { 
    var data = e.params.data.text;
    if(data=='World Wide'){
    $(".service_continent > option").prop("selected","selected");
    $(".service_continent").trigger("change");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you!

```
$('.service_continent').select2();
$('.service_continent').on('change', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).val() == 'all') {
        // select all options except first one
        $('.service_continent > option:not(:first)').prop('selected', true);

        // unselect "Select All" option
        $('.service_continent > option:first').prop('selected', false);
        $('.service_continent').trigger('change');
    }
});
```